# JQuery selector not choosing correct element with autotab

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following html to receive 2 or more telephone numbers

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Telephones" id="Telephones">
<div class="inlinediv">
                    <input maxlength="3" size="3" type ="text" data-bind="value: Prefixe" class="tab1 no-margin" style="width: 40px;" />
                    <input maxlength="3" size="3" type ="text" data-bind="value: Telephone" class="tab2 no-margin" style="width: 40px;" />
                    <input maxlength="4" size="4" type ="text" data-bind="value: Suffixe" class="tab3 no-margin" style="width: 60px;" />
                </div>
<div class="inlinediv">
                    <input maxlength="3" size="3" type ="text" data-bind="value: Prefixe" class="tab1 no-margin" style="width: 40px;" />
                    <input maxlength="3" size="3" type ="text" data-bind="value: Telephone" class="tab2 no-margin" style="width: 40px;" />
                    <input maxlength="4" size="4" type ="text" data-bind="value: Suffixe" class="tab3 no-margin" style="width: 60px;" />
                </div>
</div>
```

I am using the autotab library to type in the number without tabbing.

```
$("#Telephones .tab1").autotab({ target: $("#Telephones .tab1").next("#Telephones .tab2"), format: "numeric" });
$("#Telephones .tab2").autotab({ previous: $("#Telephones .tab1"), target: $("#Telephones .tab2").next("#Telephones .tab3"), format: "numeric" });
$("#Telephones .tab3").autotab({ previous: $("#Telephones .tab2"), target: $("#Telephones .tab3").next().next("#Telephones .tab4"), format: "numeric" });
```

The problem I am having is that the tab seems to always go to the last "inlinediv" element, meaning the first input for the first number autotabs to the second element of the last phone number, second one in this case.  I have a feeling I just need to modify my selector but Im not sure how to do it without using $(this) which does not seem to work with the autotab function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the doc there is no way you can specify the selectors especially when you have multiple matches. Had the autoTabs `target` property taken a function which evaluates at the runtime (like many plugins do) we could have easily achieved that but here this is what seems like a solution to me, because with a flat selector you cannot say for each instance of this tab1 select the next tab2. `#Telephones .tab1` will select all the `.tab1`.

```
var format = 'numeric';
$('#Telephones .inlinediv').each(function(){

    var $this = $(this);
        $tab1 = $this.find('.tab1'), 
        $tab2 = $this.find('.tab2'), 
        $tab3 =  $this.find('.tab3'),
        $next = $this.next().find('.tab1');

    $tab1.autotab({
        target: $tab2,
        format: format
     });
     $tab2.autotab({
        previous:$tab1,
        target: $tab3,
        format: format
     });
     $tab3.autotab({
        previous:$tab2,
        target: $next,
        format: format
   });

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nFmqj/)**

Comment: @jimmyjambles you are welcome, unfortly i couldnt find another way with limited options with this plugin.